# How to hide rows based on filter value in parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I am working on SSRS report. I have job number field in my report. But I would like to hide some particular job number based on value "Exclude job number" parameter.

And I am using text based parameter for accepting multiple values for Exclude job number parameter. Suppose if someone type 'ABC123' "Exclude job number" in parameter all the rows should hide from report and others show. Is there any other easy method for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best way to approach this is to have a query as your data set, in that data set add a where clause to exclude those values:

```
Select * from [Table]
where JobID not in(@JobId)
```

[image]